# OpenMDAO: How to use parallel processing for a particular subsystem while others run in serial?

Tags: openmpi, openmdao

I am carrying out static aeroelastic analysis using an OpenMDAO-based script. I am trying to adapt my script to run it on a supercomputer.

The MDA loop includes several components, including a CFD solver usually run in terminal with `mpirun -np 24 python runScript.py` and a structural solver usually run in terminal with `nast20212 nastran_static_alpha_c.bdf`.

In order to run CFD in parallel mode within my main script, I need to run it with `mpirun -np 24 python aeroelastic_mda.py`.

The issue is that when I do that, the script tries to run all components in parallel mode. However I would only need to run my CFD solver to run on multiple nodes while other components run in serial mode.

I have looked up the OpenMDAO documentation and other posts but I did not find information regarding my issue.

Below is a summarized view of my OpenMDAO script which I run with
`mpirun -np 24 python aeroelastic_mda.py`.

```
#Importing necessary modules
...  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Problem parameters
    Sw = 383.689555/2 #Wing reference surface
    V = 295.0 #Airspeed
    rho_a = 1.17 #Air density
    ... #Some other parameters
   
    root = Problem()

    #Add independent variables
    root.model.add_subsystem('wing_area', IndepVarComp('Sw', Sw), promotes=['*'])
    root.model.add_subsystem('airspeed', IndepVarComp('V', V), promotes=['*'])
    root.model.add_subsystem('air_density', IndepVarComp('rho_a', rho_a), promotes=['*'])
    ... #Some other independent variables

    mda = Group()

    #Add disciplines to the group

    # Displacement transfer: 
    # Inputs -> Displacements at structural nodes
    # Outputs -> Displacements to be applied to aerodynamic nodes 
    # Simple matrix product
    mda.add_subsystem('displacement_transfer', DisplacementTransfer(), promotes=['*'])

    # Aerodynamic solver
    mda.add_subsystem('aerodynamics', Dafoam(), promotes=['*'])

    # Load transfer
    # Inputs -> Forces at aerodynamic nodes
    # Outputs -> Forces to be applied to structural nodes 
    # Simple matrix product
    mda.add_subsystem('load_transfer', LoadTransfer(), promotes=['*'])
   
    # Structural solver
    mda.add_subsystem('structures', NastranStatic(), promotes=['*'])

    root.model.add_subsystem('mda_group', mda, promotes=['*'])

    mda.nonlinear_solver = NonlinearBlockGS()
    mda.nonlinear_solver.options['rtol'] = 1.e-3
    mda.nonlinear_solver.options['use_aitken'] = True

    mda.linear_solver = ScipyKrylov()
    root.linear_solver = ScipyKrylov()

    root.setup()
    root.run_model()
```

Also here is a simplified view of my aerodynamic component:

```
#Importing necessary modules
...
class Dafoam(ExplicitComponent):
    ... #Some constants
    
    def initialize(self):
        ... #Declaring options

    def setup(self):
        ... #Declaring inputs
        ... #Declaring outputs

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        #Generate current deformed shape
        self.create_current_geom(inputs, outputs)

        #Generate the input file for Dafoam from current geometry and flow conditions
        self.create_input_file(inputs, outputs)

        # Run DAFoam
        p = Popen(['python', 'runScript.py'])
        p.wait()

        # Parse the output file from the external code    
        ...

    def create_current_geom(self, inputs, outputs):
    ...
    #Method that creates the Dafoam input file runScript.py
    def create_input_file(self, inputs, outputs):
    ...
    def get_forces(self, inputs, outputs):
    ...
    def get_aero_coeff(self, inputs, outputs):     
    ...
```

Also here is a simplified view of my structural component:

```
#Importing necessary modules
...  
class NastranStatic(ExplicitComponent):
    ... #Some constants
    
    def initialize(self):
        ... #Declaring options

    def setup(self):
        ... #Declaring inputs
        ... #Declaring outputs

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        # Generate the input file for Nastran
        self.create_input_file(inputs, outputs)

        # Run MSC Nastran
        p = Popen(['nast20212', 'nastran_static_alpha_c.bdf'])
        p.wait()

        # Parse the output file from the external code and set output values
        ...

    def create_input_file(self, inputs, outputs):
    ...
    def get_output_data(self, inputs, outputs):
    ...
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: From your question its not 100% clear, but it sounds like you are trying to have an OpenMDAO component which makes a subprocess call to run your  aero_analysis.py. If that is the case, this is the wrong approach to using MPI. To give you a real answer though could you provide a toy example that at least shows the structure of your components and model and any relevant run commands you use?

Comment: @JustinGray thank you for your answer. I have added simplified views of my main OpenMDAO script, aerodynamic and structural components. When I run the main script under MPI, CFD solver successfully  runs under MPI, but the main script also attempts to run the structural solver under MPI as well even if, as I know, it doesn’t support MPI. Please tell me if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have eventually solved my issue by replacing Popen by ShellProc (openmdao.utils.shell_proc) function. For some reason, Popen did not work properly when used with mpirun command.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, it is hard to give you a precise answer. However, it sounds like you have a component making a sub-process call to try and run the CFD under MPI, while the OpenMDAO model itself runs serially on top.

This is generally speaking the wrong approach with OpenMDAO. The framework itself is MPI aware and components can declare distributed inputs/outputs. The [docs on distributed IO](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.21.0/features/core_features/working_with_components/distributed_components.html) give some decent examples to look at.

I would also recommend you check out the [Mphys library](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/mphys), which is built on top of OpenMDAO and has a lot of aerostructural examples to work from.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider just running your top level script serially, with just `python aeroelastic_mda.py`, and modify your Popen calls to run the subprocesses using mpirun, for example `Popen(['mpirun', '-np', '24', 'nast20212', 'nastran_static_alpha_c.bdf'])`.  You could also modify your top level script to accept command line arguments to specify the number of processes you want to use with your calls to nastran and Dafoam.

Comment: @BretNeylor thank you for your answer. That was my first idea, but for some reason Popen(['mpirun', '-np', '24', 'python','runScript.py']) does not work my the OpenMDAO environment. The component code simply does not run and exit immediately.

Comment: Did you get an error message when you tried that?  If so could you post it?  I just tried it with a simple python script and a sub-script and it worked just fine.

Comment: No unfortunately I get no particular message. I have tried to do it with a simple script as you did, it worked just fine as long as I do not import the OpenMDAO API. Maybe you can try to add it to your script to see if you can replicate the issue?